# Can a map's key be shared with part of the value?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can a `std::map`'s or `std::unordered_map`'s key be shared with part of the value? Especially if the key is non-trivial, say like a `std::string`?

As a simple example let's take a Person object:

```
struct Person {
    // lots of other values
    std::string name;
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Person>> people;
void insertPerson(std::shared_ptr<Person>& p) {
    people[p.name] = p;
    //    ^^^^^^
    //    copy of name string
}

std::shared_ptr<Person> lookupPerson(const std::string& name) const {
    return people[name];
}
```

My first thought is a wrapper around the name that points to the person, but I cannot figure out how to do a lookup by name.

Comment: You might look at C++14's heterogenous lookup (possibly in a `set` rather than a `map`).

Comment: Referring to data as keys is problematic unless you can guarantee that that data is immutable. But given that, just outfit your `map` with a suitable comparison function. One that compares the values referred to by the keys.

Comment: Okay, I can't find it in my draft, it looks like heterogenous lookup missed C++14? Maybe it will be in C++17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose, a `std::map` can be considered a `std::set` containing `std::pair`'s which is ordered (and thus efficiently accessible) according to the first element of the pair.

This view is particularly useful if key and value elements are partly identical, because then you do not need to artificially separate value and key elements for a set (and neither you need to write wrappers around the values which select the key).

Instead, one only has to provide a custom ordering function which works on the set and extracts the relevant key part.

Following this idea, your example becomes

```
auto set_order = [](auto const& p, auto const& s) { return p->name < s->name; };

std::set<std::shared_ptr<Person>, decltype(set_order)> people(set_order);

void insertPerson(std::shared_ptr<Person>& p) {
    people.insert(p);
}
```

As an alternative, here you could also drop the custom comparison and order the set by the addresses in the shared pointer (which supports `<` and thus can be used directly in the set):

```
std::set<std::shared_ptr<Person> > people;

void insertPerson(std::shared_ptr<Person>& p) {
    people.insert(p);
}
```

Replace `set` by `unordered_set` where needed (in general you then also need to provide a suitable hash function).

**EDIT**: The lookup can be performed using `std:lower_bound`:

```
std::shared_ptr<Person> lookupPerson(std::string const& s)
{
    auto comp =  [](auto const& p, auto const& s) { return p->name < s; };
    return *std::lower_bound(std::begin(people), std::end(people), s, comp);
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf8e853018db9264).

---

**EDIT 2**: However, given this more-or-less ugly stuff, you can also follow the lines of your primary idea and use a small wrapper around the value as key, something like

```
struct PersonKey
{
    PersonKey(std::shared_ptr<Person> const& p) : s(p->name) {}
    PersonKey(std::string const& _s) : s(_s) {}

    std::string s;
    bool operator<(PersonKey const& rhs) const
    {
         return s < rhs.s;
    }
};
```

Use it like (untested)

```
std::map<PersonKey, std::shared_ptr<Person> > m;
auto sptr = std::make_shared<Person>("Peter");
m[PersonKey(sptr)]=sptr;
```

Lookup is done through

```
m[PersonKey("Peter")];
```

Now I like this better than my first suggestion ;-)

Comment: But how to do a lookup by name?

Comment: Correct, that is not that trivial as I implied in my answer ... made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to davidhigh's answer.

```
struct Person {
    // lots of other values
    std::string name;
}

struct StrPtrCmp {
    bool operator()(const std::string* a, const std::string* b) const {
        return *a < *b;
    }
}

std::map<const std::string*, std::shared_ptr<Person>, StrPtrCmp> people();
void insertPerson(std::shared_ptr<Person>& p) {
    people[&(p.name)] = p;
}

std::shared_ptr<Person> lookupPerson(const std::string& name) const {
    return people[&name];
}
```

And a few edits to make it work with `std::unordered_map`:

```
struct StrPtrHash {
    size_t operator()(const std::string* p) const {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(*p);
    }
};

struct StrPtrEquality {
    bool operator()(const std::string* a, const std::string* b) const {
        return std::equal_to<std::string>()(*a, *b);
    }
};

std::unordered_map<const std::string*, std::shared_ptr<Person>, StrPtrHash, StrPtrEquality> people();
```